# LWJGL on ARM (Minecraft on BBB)

Tags: compilation, lwjgl, minecraft, armv7, beagleboneblack

Still chasing that white whale of running Minecraft on an BBB, I eventually came to the conclusion that the major issue was twofold. First, Minecraft has a dependency on the Lightweight Java Games Library, or LWJGL, and it does not have an ARM version to reference when it's downloading the run environment. Second, Minecraft's launcher doesn't allow you to reference specific jars in the boot up process, meaning that any version of LWJGL and it's accessories that could be ported to ARM would also have to pass the sha checks. Granted, those could be fudged, but I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed since I seem to be in uncharted territory. Anyone have any pieces of advice or suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: I came across this page: http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=5331.0;wap2

Is this something you posted as well? lol

Comment: Yep. That's my baby right there.

Answer (score 0):

I am also in the same boat, trying to do the same thing.

All I know for sure so far:

- JWJGL is built for x86, so it can't run on ARM processor - we would need to recompile for ARM.
- There is a checksum when you do replace the LWJGL library, which triggers minecraft to replace the file with the x86 version.

I had an idea that, in order to get around the checksum issue, if someone with the know how could make a mod that also included the LWJGL for ARM. In this manner, as I understand it, getting MC to run on BBB would be as simple as copying over a mod.

Sorry I couldn't help further. I'll keep an eye on this post and I'll let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some information here for LWJGL for ARM:
    http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=19532

This brought me to 2 places:

- More info on running ARM LWJGL: http://www.trimslice.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=393
- And, what appears to be precompiled LWJGL for ARM: http://openjdk.gudinna.com/lwjgl-es/

I have yet to test anything, but it's a step in the direction. I am new to a lot of this myself, so we'll see where it goes.

Comment: Good on you, here is what I can bring to the party. The LWJGL compile can be done with a couple ln pokes. https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/74

Comment: You also run into some huge issues with OpenGL since without a Tegra K1, OpenGL has to be software emulated, which means slow game. But there is hope, since lumixbochs released a project called glshim https://github.com/lunixbochs/glshim, designed to make the conversion. Ptitseb forked it, and rolled it into his version of Minecraft with the OpenPandora. http://boards.openpandora.org/topic/16617-beta-minecraft-launcher/